# List of hardware-based sensors and software-based sensors

Tags: android

I have a list of sensors used in android-powered devices. Please help me to sort this list by "Hardware-Based Sensors" and "Software-Based Sensors".

1. GPS sensor
2. Ambient temperature sensor
3. Uncalibrated rotation vector sensor
4. Geo-magnetic rotation vector sensor
5. Gravity sensor
6. Gyroscope sensor
7. Uncalibrated gyroscope sensor
8. Light sensor
9. Linear acceleration sensor
10. Magnetic field sensor
11. Uncalibrated magnetic field sensor
12. Pressure sensor
13. Proximity sensor
14. Relative humidity sensor
15. Rotation vector sensor
16. Significant motion trigger sensor
17. Step counter sensor
18. Step detector sensor
19. Barometer sensor
20. NFC sensor
21. Magnetometer sensor
22. Photometer sensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on device. Hardware would be 2, 5, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14. Where did you get this list? You make up or repeat sensors.
Go here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/index.html.

Comment: Thanks JacMobile. Part of the list is from the dev-guide. If "Uncalibrated magnetic field sensor" is hardware-based then what about #7?

Comment: I'm not sure honestly. I guess it's probably usually hardware. Not a lot of devices have it.